# PHY core voltage not proper

Tags: voltage, power, current, ethernet, phy

I'm using this Ethernet [PHY](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/8720a.pdf) where I'm using an internal regulator for 1V2 by pulling down the LED1/REGOFF Pin.

But few boards are generating 0v9 or 0v8 and few boards are not generating VDDCR Supply itself.

In some of the boards, VVDCR is 1.2V which is fine but in some boards, it's working and in some, it's not working even if the VDDCR is 1.2V. Unable to fetch MAC & PING too!

What might be the reason and how to solve

Comment: Did you follow the ref schematic and place the recommended capacitors across VDDCR pin? Is your 3.3~3.6V supply is clean and stable?

Comment: These chips can be quite finicky with the reset signal. Have you verified that you fulfill the timing requirements given in figure 5.3 ? Otherwise, sampling of the config pin strappings may fail.

Comment: Sure, thank you. Let me check and get back soon

Comment: How did you connect the REGOFF strap? And the LED to that pin? Or power supplies? Post the schematics.

Comment: Is it OK if I connect 1uF and 1nF capacitor on the VDDCR pin? The Datasheet recommends 1uF and 470pF.